# Что значит ".=" в php?

Tags: php

Не могу найти значение символа `.=` (точка равно ) в php. И не могу понять, что означает `$key&`, конкретно зачем амперсанд в конце. Создаю функцию по удалению `get`-параметра из url.

Пример:

```
$ulr .= "$key&"
```

Comment: `$ulr .= "$key&"` == `$ulr = $ulr."$key&"` http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php *зачем амперсант в конце* Да просто литерал... разделитель параметров в URL, вероятно. И эта... в слове "амперсанд" нет буквы "т".

Comment: амперсанд это просто символ. То есть, если $key был равен 123, то к строке $url будет дописана строка "123&"

Comment: `parse_url`, `parse_str`, `unset` и `implode` вам в помощь

Comment: хотя можно и `preg_replace`-ом все решить

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в переменную
Например:
$a = 'abc';
$a .= '123';
echo $a; //Выведит abc123